# CheckBox DelegateCommand not firing

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

I have seen many similar questions posted, but I think mine may be different enough to warrant posting it.

I am simply migrating the sample Azure Mobile Services application to Windows 10 UWP and trying to keep everything MVVM. I have a `ListView` that has a `DataTemplate` that looks like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxComplete"
                      Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewModel, Path=UpdateCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                      Margin="10,5"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Content="{Binding Text}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Complete,
                                          Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Everything compiles fine, but the `UpdateCommand` is not firing. I have set a breakpoint to make sure that the correct value would be passed as the `CommandParameter`, but the `Command` is not firing. Is it possible to use a `DelegateCommand` on a `CheckBox` that is inside of a `DataTemplate`?

Or will I have to use attached behaviors to achieve something like this?

**EDIT**

The original `CheckBox` looked like this, with the click event handler in the code-behind:

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckBoxComplete" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Complete, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Checked="CheckBoxComplete_Checked" 
          Content="{Binding Text}" 
          Margin="10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

**EDIT2**

Posting entire XAML by request:

```
<Page x:Class="MyMoney10.Views.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
      xmlns:common="using:MyMoney10.Common"
      xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
      xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
      xmlns:local="using:MyMoney10.Views"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:models="using:MyMoney10.Models"
      xmlns:vm="using:MyMoney10.ViewModels"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <RelativePanel.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </RelativePanel.ChildrenTransitions>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for narrow view  -->
                        <!--<Setter Target="StateTextBox.Text" Value="Narrow Visual State" />-->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for normal view  -->
                        <!--<Setter Target="StateTextBox.Text" Value="Normal Visual State" />-->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <!--  TODO: change properties for wide view  -->
                        <!--<Setter Target="StateTextBox.Text" Value="Wide Visual State" />-->
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <controls:PageHeader x:Name="PageHeader" Text="MyMoney">
            <!--  place stretched, across top  -->
            <RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel>
            <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
            <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
            <!--  secondary commands  -->
            <controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoSettings}" Label="Settings" />
                <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoPrivacy}" Label="Privacy" />
                <AppBarButton Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoAbout}" Label="About" />
            </controls:PageHeader.SecondaryCommands>
        </controls:PageHeader>

        <controls:Resizer x:Name="ParameterResizer" Margin="16,16,16,0">

            <!--  place below page header  -->

            <RelativePanel.Below>PageHeader</RelativePanel.Below>
            <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
            <TextBox MinWidth="250"
                     MinHeight="62"
                     Header="Parameter to pass"
                     Text="{Binding Value,
                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    <!--  enable submit on enter key  -->

                    <behaviors:KeyBehavior Key="Enter">
                        <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GotoDetailsPage" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                    </behaviors:KeyBehavior>

                    <!--  focus on textbox when page loads  -->

                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        <behaviors:FocusAction />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </controls:Resizer>

        <Button x:Name="SubmitButton"
                Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoDetailsPage}"
                Content="Submit">

            <!--  place next to textbox  -->

            <RelativePanel.RightOf>ParameterResizer</RelativePanel.RightOf>
            <RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith>ParameterResizer</RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock x:Name="StateTextBox"
                   Margin="16,16,0,0"
                   Text="Current Visual State">

            <!--  place under to textbox  -->

            <RelativePanel.Below>ParameterResizer</RelativePanel.Below>
            <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith>ParameterResizer</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith>
        </TextBlock>

        <Grid>
            <RelativePanel.Below>StateTextBox</RelativePanel.Below>
            <RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel>
            <RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel>
            <RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel>True</RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel>
            <Grid Margin="50,50,10,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Margin="0,0,0,20">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,6"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                                   Foreground="#0094ff">
                            MICROSOFT AZURE MOBILE SERVICES
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                                   FontSize="45"
                                   Foreground="Gray">
                            MyMoney10
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <common:QuickStartTask Title="Insert a TodoItem"
                                               Description="Enter some text below and click Save to insert a new todo item into your database"
                                               Number="1" />

                        <StackPanel Margin="72,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="TextInput"
                                     MinWidth="300"
                                     Margin="5" />
                            <Button Name="ButtonSave"
                                    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SaveCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TextInput,
                                                               Path=Text}"
                                    IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.SaveEnabled}">
                                Save
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <common:QuickStartTask Title="Query and Update Data"
                                               Description="Click refresh below to load the unfinished TodoItems from your database. Use the checkbox to complete and update your TodoItems"
                                               Number="2" />
                        <Button Name="ButtonRefresh"
                                Margin="72,0,0,0"
                                Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.RefreshCommand}"
                                IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.RefreshEnabled}">
                            Refresh
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <ListView Name="ListItems"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Margin="62,10,0,0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding TodoItems}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxComplete"
                                              Margin="10,5"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewModel,
                                                                Path=UpdateCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                              Content="{Binding Text}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding Complete,
                                                                  Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewModel, Path=UpdateCommand}" if replaced with Command="{Binding ElementName=ViewModel, Path=DataContext.UpdateCommand}" should solve the issue

Comment: I get a warning about `Cannot resolve property 'DataContext' in data context of type 'App.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel'`.. I tried it anyway, but it still doesn't work. I think adding `DataContext` would be redundant anyway, as that is already implied when you are binding to something.

Comment: Can you post the entire xaml?

Comment: added xaml in new edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the checkbox binding to elementname="viewmodel" is the issue. Because viewmodel is not a name of an element.

So give your page a name and put that name in the binding. With path=Datacontext.UpdateCommand

Comment: `ViewModel` is an element name. See above where it sets the `Page.DataContext` with `x:Name="ViewModel"`

Comment: I tried as you suggested, and that did work. I still am not understanding why it didn't work with `ElementName=ViewModel` and `Path=UpdateCommand`..

Comment: Elementname is for xaml elements whereas in your case with viewmodel its not name of a xaml ui element and so it did not work.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the clarification.